# Load DLL exported data dynamically

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport, dynamic-loading

Is there a version of GetProcAddress for exported data?

I would like to do something like:

Mydll.cpp:

```
MyDataType::MyDataType(long, wchar_t*)
{
    //Dummy code
    this->temp = 3;
}
__declspec(dllexport) MyDataType Here(50, L"random text");
```

MyClient.cpp:

```
int main(void)
{
    HINSTANCE hData = LoadLibrary("MyDll.dll");
    reinterpret_cast<MyDataType*>(GetDataAddress(hData, "Here"))->DoSomething();
}
```

That is, define an exported data ("Here") of UDT ("MyDataType"), and them obtain its address when the DLL is dynamically loaded.  Is this possible?

Comment: the msdn page says  "Retrieves the address of an exported function or variable from the specified dynamic-link library (DLL)." - ie it should Just Work(tm)

Comment: I'm going to agree with pm100.
What part of the process you described _isn't_ done when the DLL is loaded at runtime?

Comment: Check the exports from mydll.cpp.  I don't know what sort of mangling `__declspec(dllexport)` puts on a name, but there's probably something so the GetProcAddress call would fail to locate the symbol using just `Here` and you'll need to use the full mangled name.

Comment: @pm100 Make it an answer, and I'll give you a check mark.  Thanks; I (foolishly) assumed I knew what GetProcAddress did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the msdn page says "Retrieves the address of an exported function or **variable** from the specified dynamic-link library (DLL)." - ie it should Just Work(tm)