# Having trouble importing from a DLL

Tags: c++

So I am trying to import a database ( stored as an array )from a DLL, but not sure why I cannot do it, it's not showing errors and as far as I can tell it should be doing it, any help?

```
 int import(char * dllname, char * filename, SalesData salesData[], int countData, int max_size)
{
    SalesData allData[MAX_SALES_DATA];
    int countData = 0;
    countData = import("dll_CSV.dll", "..\\Debug\\txt.import", allData, countData, MAX_SALES_DATA);
    if (countData < 0)
    {
        cout << "Import failed" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

SalesData is my header file, it's in main where I'm struggling to call it back

Comment: Why are you calling `import` *recursively*? You have an infinite recursion in the code you show. This should have been very clear if you just used the debugger to step through the code!

Comment: no question here

Comment: Where have I done that? Don't fully understand Recursion yet tbh

Comment: The joke goes: "Recursion: See recursion"... Read about it e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). In your specific code you have a function `import` which calls the function `import` which calls the function `import`... etc. for all eternity.

Comment: ah so its caught in like an infinite loop, so I need to figure out how to get it out of the loop per se

Comment: Indeed. What were you hoping for the call to `import` to do? At the moment it calls itself. You need to actually get the data from the dll somewhere

Comment: I wanted to import the data from the DLL into an array of allData, countData and MAX_Sales_data

Comment: I wonder if this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193790/load-dll-exported-data-dynamically will point you in the right direction

Comment: hmm, kinda, still struggling a bit with getting it out of a loop